# Sending a Notification by an AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-service

I want every minute to push a notifaction and a tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990

But the problem is, that the alarm doesn't run.
I tried to set Logs but I can't see them...

Now I've started a new project and here are my files, maybe one import is wrong, but I don't know...:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onCreate");
    }
}
```

**Alarm.java**

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        // Put here YOUR code.
        Log.e("Alarm", "onReceive");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

        wl.release();
    }

    public void setAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Log.e("Alarm", "setAlarm");
        AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        // Changed to 1 minute
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

**YourService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e("Service", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e("Service", "onStartCommand");
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.setAlarm(this);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It's the same code like in the link, i just only changed the time to one minute...
Here is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--AutoStart Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name="com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest.AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Receiver and Permisson added -->
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest.Alarm"></receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

    <!-- Added my Service -->
    <service
        android:name=".YourService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":your_service" >
    </service>
</application>
```

There is nothing in the Android Monitor like "E/Alarm: onReceive" and for example the toast also doesn't start.
To be honest I tried everything, also tried this here: http://it-ride.blogspot.de/2010/10/android-implementing-notification.html

Could someone help me please and is it the right way to push a notification? 
Using API 16 now...

**App Logcat:**

```
11-02 21:48:19.234 3433-3433/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 234: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 237: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:19.726 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest, real application class is null.
11-02 21:48:19.734 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1886 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x025e
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1886 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
11-02 21:48:19.742 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0060
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16034: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16036: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16040: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 721: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 743: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-02 21:48:20.101 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
11-02 21:48:20.437 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
11-02 21:48:20.437 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16467: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
11-02 21:48:20.437 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.453 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
11-02 21:48:20.453 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 449: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
11-02 21:48:20.453 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 684: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 686: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
11-02 21:48:20.460 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-02 21:48:20.476 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
11-02 21:48:20.476 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 149 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
11-02 21:48:20.476 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
11-02 21:48:20.648 3433-3438/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 235K, 20% free 5386K/6664K, paused 5ms+6ms, total 32ms
11-02 21:48:20.656 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest E/MainActivity: onCreate
11-02 21:48:20.906 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
11-02 21:48:20.960 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
11-02 21:48:20.976 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
11-02 21:48:20.992 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/GC: <tid=3433> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver SS_rls_pxa988_JB42_R1_RC2_GC13.15 
11-02 21:48:21.046 3433-3433/com.example.alarm.alarmmanagertest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
```

**Non-App Logcat:**

```
1-02 21:59:45.765 515-617/? V/AlarmManager: trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
11-02 21:59:49.914 515-592/? I/Monitor: SIOP:: Current AP = 380, CP = 0, PST = 380
11-02 21:59:52.914 515-607/? D/BatteryService: update start
11-02 21:59:52.921 515-607/? D/BatteryService: level:100, scale:100, status:3, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4325, temperature: 220, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303457, invalid charger:0, online:4, charge type:1, current avg:450
11-02 21:59:52.921 515-592/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
11-02 21:59:52.929 775-775/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController: onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
11-02 21:59:52.929 775-775/? D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController: onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING: tw_stat_sys_battery_usb_not_charge
11-02 21:59:52.953 775-775/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(390), More:false, Req:false Child:13
11-02 21:59:52.968 775-775/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true
11-02 21:59:57.664 515-615/? I/PowerManagerService: [PWL] Off : 105s ago
11-02 21:59:59.921 515-592/? I/Monitor: SIOP:: Current AP = 380, CP = 0, PST = 380
11-02 21:59:59.992 515-617/? V/AlarmManager: waitForAlarm result :8
11-02 22:00:00.007 3817-3817/? D/KeyguardClockWidgetService: onReceive action=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
11-02 22:00:00.015 515-592/? V/AlarmManager: ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
11-02 22:00:00.054 775-775/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(390), More:false, Req:false Child:13
11-02 22:00:03.015 515-607/? D/BatteryService: update start
11-02 22:00:05.039 515-595/? W/ProcessStats: Skipping unknown process pid 14477
11-02 22:00:05.039 515-595/? W/ProcessStats: Skipping unknown process pid 14479
11-02 22:00:05.039 515-595/? W/ProcessStats: Skipping unknown process pid 14480
11-02 22:00:09.929 515-592/? I/Monitor: SIOP:: Current AP = 380, CP = 0, PST = 380
11-02 22:00:12.062 515-837/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1050
11-02 22:00:12.078 515-617/? V/AlarmManager: waitForAlarm result :4
```

You can see, that there is something from the AlarmManager, but I think it's from an other App. Should I unstill my other Apps where I tried to work with the AlarmManager and restart my device?

Comment: Where and how do you call `SetAlarm()`?

Comment: I start the alarm with the service:
 alarm.setAlarm(this);

or also with the AutoStart.java:
 if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
        {
            alarm.setAlarm(context);
        }


you can see it here, I use the same code like here, just edited the time to one minute, added Logs and also maybe the manifest.xml is wrong... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys I tried this one and it finally worked!

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

So if you want to run an **AlarmManager and send a Notificiation**, that opens your Application by clicking on it, here is the code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Permission to start Alarm on device reboot -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <activity
        android:name="alarmservice.javatechig.com.alarmservice.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="alarmservice.javatechig.com.alarmservice.AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
    <receiver android:name="alarmservice.javatechig.com.alarmservice.DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlarmManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.util.Calendar;

 public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    findViewById(R.id.startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            start();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancel();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarmAt10).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startAt10();
        }
    });
}

public void start() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 8000;

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Log.e("Alarm","started");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void cancel() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void startAt10() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 20;

    /* Set the alarm to start at 10:30 AM */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 27);

    /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);
}
```

}

**DeviceBootReceiver.java**

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * @author Neel
 *         <p/>
 *         Broadcast reciever, starts when the device gets starts.
 *         Start your repeating alarm here.
 */
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            /* Setting the alarm here */

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            int interval = 8000;

            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
        System.out.println("running");
        Log.e("Alarm","running");

        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Finally");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

The Source again: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android
Some tips:

- in `<receiver android:name="">` write the whole name
- don't forget the uses-permission
- start a new project, insert this code and try to unterstand how it works
- after that you can put in your project

Answer (score 1):

Your `<receiver>` block in the manifest for the `Alarm` broadcast receiver is incorrect. The `name` attribute needs the FQN of the class or the shorthand `".Alarm"`, assuming that the class is part of the package declared at the top of the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you! That's true, but it wasn't the solution :/

Now I've started a new project and also updated my question.

Comment: Check the logcat, it should show some useful information.  Turn off any app specific filtering and look at the raw logcat output.  Unless you have a specific need, you may want to remove the `android:process` attribute from the broadcast receiver (and service) declarations in the manifest.  It's possible that could be interfering with `Toast` being shown on screen (though not very likely.)

Comment: Okay thanks, i added the logcat output. 
And also removed the `android:process` and it's still the same...

Comment: Is your `Service` ever actually running and setting the alarm?  This article may help you: http://po.st/7UpipA.  It doesn't take into account doze mode (Marshmallow+), but covers the basics and has demo code.

Comment: Thank you Larry :)